# Get values from a JSON array nested in another array for use in codenameone project using a loop

Tags: arrays, json, loops, codenameone

I have a JSON array that has two other arrays in it. I would like to retrieve values from both arrays using a loop. the arrays are from a hashed table. Am doing this in a codenameone project. Here is me array from a hashtable:

```
{2={company=helsana, monthly_amount=100, gender=male, dob=2007, vorname=King, fname=Brian , cid=1, id=2}, 1={company=helsana, monthly_amount=150, gender=female, dob=1985, vorname=King, fname=Lorna, cid=1, id=1}}
```

Here is my code to get the values so far, which is so not working. Am stuck(I have put "?" where I don't know what to use to get the values). The values are "fname" and "vorname" from each of the arrays.

```
final String[] anArray;
             final String[] secArray;
             anArray = new String[]{String.valueOf(h.get(?))};
             secArray = new String[]{String.valueOf(h.get(?))};


             final Button[] button = new Button[h.size()];
             for (int i = 0; i < h.size(); i++) {
                button[i] = new Button(); 
                button[i].setIcon(fetchResourceFile().getImage("personIconBig.png"));
                button[i].setText(""+anArray[i]);
                final String name = String.valueOf(anArray[i]);
                final String secname = String.valueOf(secArray[i]);

                button[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    findName().setText(name);
                    findVorname().setText(secname);
                    findFamMname().setText(name+" "+secname);
                    findFamMname().setIcon(fetchResourceFile().getImage("personIconBig.png"));
                    findFamMname2().setText(name+" "+secname);
                    findFamMname2().setIcon(fetchResourceFile().getImage("personIconBig.png"));
                    findDeleteMember().setVisible(true);

                    c.getComponentForm().revalidate();
                    c.getComponentForm().repaint();

                    }
                });
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
int size = h.size()+1;
             final Button[] button = new Button[size];
             for (int i = 1; i <size ; i++) {
                button[i] = new Button(); 
                button[i].setIcon(fetchResourceFile().getImage("personIconBig.png"));
                Result evaluator = Result.fromContent(h);
                String fname = String.valueOf(evaluator.get("/"+i+"/fname"));
                String vorname = String.valueOf(evaluator.get("/"+i+"/vorname"));
                String dob = String.valueOf(evaluator.get("/"+i+"/dob"));
                System.out.println(""+i);

                button[i].setText(fname);
                final String name = fname;
                final String secname = vorname;
                final String DOB = dob;

                button[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    findName().setText(name);
                    findVorname().setText(secname);
                    findDOB().setText(DOB);
                    findFamMname().setText(name+" "+secname);
                    findFamMname().setIcon(fetchResourceFile().getImage("personIconBig.png"));
                    findFamMname2().setText(name+" "+secname);
                    findFamMname2().setIcon(fetchResourceFile().getImage("personIconBig.png"));
                    findDeleteMember().setVisible(true);

                    c.getComponentForm().revalidate();
                    c.getComponentForm().repaint();

                    }
                });
```